# How to find payment method type when querying Braintree in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, braintree-rails

I'm trying to query the payment method associated with a `Braintree::Customer`. I would like to display the type of the payment method(s) attached to the account and additional information (last 4 digits of card number if it's a credit card; email if it's a Paypal account).

I cannot find any documentation on how to retrieve the type of the `Braintree::PaymentMethod` object (i.e. whether it's a credit card or a Paypal account).

This is important because I need to access attributes that are exclusive to either types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I completely forgot about Ruby's native methods and how to compare objects...

You can do a simple comparison by using the `.class` method

e.g.

```
if Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(token).class == Braintree::PayPalAccount
   payment_type = 'Paypal'
elsif Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(token).class == Braintree::CreditCard
   payment_type = 'Credit Card'
end
```